# Cannot seem to remove an object item from an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, primefaces

I am not able to remove an item from a arraylist.
What i tried is pasted below. Cannot seem to figure out what is wrong in below code.
The xhtml is

```
<p:dataTable id="emaildt" styleClass="hide-column-names"
    style="width:70%" rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
    value="#{myBean.emailAddressList}" var="email">
    <p:column style="width:15%">
        <p:inputText id="email" value="#{email.email}"
        validatorMessage="Invalid email" onblur="TrimString(this)">
            <f:validateRegex
            pattern="^(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$" />
            <p:ajax event="blur"  
                global="false" listener="#{myBean.checkEmailExist(email)}" />
        </p:inputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="width:13%">
        <p:spacer width="10" rendered="#{myBean.emailAddressList.size()>'1'}"/>
        <p:commandLink  id="delete" immediate="true"
            actionListener="#{myBean.removeEmailFromList}"
            update="emaildt" process="emaildt"
            rendered="#{myBean.emailAddressList.size()>'1' &amp;&amp; false}">
                <h:graphicImage value="../images/button_remove.gif" />
                <f:param name="rowToRemove" value="#{rowIndex}" />
        </p:commandLink>

        <p:spacer width="5" rendered="#{rowIndex == myBean.emailAddressList.size()-1}"/>

        <p:commandLink id="addemailbtn" immediate="true"
            actionListener="#{myBean.addEmail}" 
            style="float:right;" update="emaildt" process="@this emaildt" 
            rendered="#{rowIndex == myBean.emailAddressList.size()-1}">

            <h:graphicImage value="../images/addbutton.jpg" />
        </p:commandLink>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Create a model class EmailAddressModel with string email and its getters and setters.

MyBean code is

```
List<emailAddressList> emailAddressList; //make its getters and setters
@PostConstruct
public void fillPage() {

    emailAddressList = new ArrayList<EmailAddressModel>();
    emailAddressList.add(new EmailAddressModel());

}

public void addEmail()  {
    try 
    {

        EmailAddressModel emailAddress = new EmailAddressModel();
        emailAddressList.add(emailAddress);
    }
    catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException I) {
        log.warn("FL Warning", I);

    }
}

public void removeEmailFromList() {
    String rowIndex = null;
    try {
        rowIndex = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getRequestParameterMap().get("rowToRemove");
        int index = Integer.parseInt(rowIndex);
        emailAddressList.remove(index);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn("FL Warning", e);
    }
}
```

Issue is -> after we add and enter the values to first and second remove, click on delete of first row, then the second row gets deleted. On debugging, the first row is gets removed in backend arraylist but in front end, the second row gets deleted.

Hope that the above information is helpful.

Comment: Arrays in Java are zero indexed. That sounds like your issue.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: code uses arraylist. as explained in question, when i click the delete of first row, the row index received in back end is zero itself, ie, to remove the object at index zero. and removes the correct row from the arraylist.

Comment: what row is removed in the backend and frontend if you click the 4th row?

Comment: Suppose i have 4 rows only, and i click delete of the 4th row, index received in backend is 3, the 4th row gets removed in UI also - correct..but if have 5 rows and try to delete 4th row, index recieved in backend is 3 and the 5th row gets deleted in ui - wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution added atrribute **resetValues="true"** to **p:commandLink**.
Thank you all helping me..:)

Comment: ??? This is not what I have to do... You most likely have a different original problem then. Validation errors or something. I took a little closer look and what if you remove the 'process="emaildt"' from the delete button? And maybe change it to 'process="@this"' (I always forget the default of the pf buttons)

Comment: I donot want to change the process attribute's value. when delete button is clicked i want to process the whole datatable so that the value will be received in the backing bean..the above issue still exists if the process's value is changed to @this..

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of what's passed to rowIndex, as Boris the Spider mentioned, Java is zero indexed.

It's likely you're returning a rowIndex of 1, when the first item is indexed at 0.

To test, In your try-catch block you could use:

```
 int index = Integer.parseInt(rowIndex) - 1;
```

Comment: i used this method but this time, no row gets removed. the index received in back end is correct.